# spring security. forward after login page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

It is snippet from spring security config:

```
<form-login login-page="/home.jsp"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" default-target-url="/index" />
               <logout logout-success-url="/logOut" />
```

But if I enter successfull I was forward to `/logOut`

if click log out - go to `home.jsp` .

if failed login - `home.jsp`

What is the strange behaviour?

**update**

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
   <!--  -->


    <import resource="classpath:spring/BeanConfig.xml" />
    <!-- Файл с настройками Security -->
    <import resource="security_config.xml" />
<!--    <bean id="messageSource"        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource‌​"> -->
<!--        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" /> -->
<!--    </bean> -->

</beans>
```

securuty_config.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
   <http use-expressions="true" >   

        <intercept-url pattern="/home.jsp" access="permitAll" /> 

        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()"/> 


        <form-login login-page="/home.jsp"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" default-target-url="/index" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logOut" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="provider" /> 
<!-- <authentication-provider> -->
<!--    <user-service> -->
<!--    <user name="name" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> -->
<!--    </user-service> -->
<!-- </authentication-provider> -->
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

form authenthification fragment:

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check" />"
```

Comment: Please provide content of `web.xml` and the part of the XML spring configuration file related to Spring Security.

Comment: What's the action value of your form.  Remove the login-page attribute from above config and give it a try.Spring security will provide the login page in this case.

Comment: I added all information to topic.

Comment: no ideas for my quesion?

Comment: Try with `always-use-default-target="true"` in `form-login`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @user2740224 can you try in `security_config.xml` something like this:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
<http use-expressions="true" >
     <intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
     <form-login login-page="/home" default-target-url="/index" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
     <logout logout-success-url="/home" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
     ...
</http>
```

**I hope help you :)**